# Which option is better to extend a feature 1) add a property or 2) create a new table?

Tags: grails, domain-model

Suppose i have a Cat domain as shown below.

```
  class Cat{

     String name
     Integer age

    }
```

Now i want to add a new feature that will assign tags to cats.

Now i see two options to achieve this.

**Option 1**

add a property to the Cat domain

```
class Cat{

 String name
 Integer age
 String tag

}
```

**Option 2**

Create a new table

```
class CatTagAssignment{

 Cat cat
 String tag

 static mapping = {

        id composite: ['cat', 'tag']

    }

}
```

I am trying to understand which is a better approach or which one should i prefer when i want to add a new feature? I appreciate it if you can offer pros and cons of both approach and whether one approach is always preferable to the other. I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a tag model (define your tags), and a cattag model (relate tags to cats). Should you ever want to be able to 'tag' something else, it's a simple join table to the new model.

Which to prefer? Ignore code and frameworks and think about what you are modeling.

Tags as a separate entity are more reusable, and a cat remains a cat (is a tag *really* an attribute of a cat?). Good models should be transferable across database, framework, language.

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplest model you can get. Don't use the extra tables for the sake of "object orientation" alone, unless there's no other option.

I would pick 1) as it's the fastest possible way to load objects, although the tag lookup can get a bit tricky (`like` query)

Comment: one cons i notice is that in future adding more and more columns to a table will make the table size really big. can we opt for option 2 in such cases? Thanks!